# div height and width 100% follows page screen size not the element size inside

Tags: css, html, popup

I have

```
<div id=overlay>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

the height and width of the outer div is set to 100%.

What happens here is, the 100% refers to the size of the element inside (inside div).

I have a dynamically changing element on inside div, and I wanted to be my outer div got the size of the page screen.

NOTE that these div (outer and inside) are a popup element. So I wanted to cover all other elements behind the popup that's why I need the 100% of the page behind.

this is my css for the outer div

```
#overlay {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%; 
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;      
 height: auto !important;
 width: auto !important;       
 text-align:center;
 z-index: 1000; 
 background-image:url(template/popup-bg.png); 
}
```

my js

```
function overlay(e) 
{
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Comment: how do you open the popup using `javascript.window.open()` if yes then rep.

Comment: You have declared height twice in your style. Use one. And are you sure you need a background image for the overlay. I think one background color with some opacity will do the job. Because image of full screen size is heavy, might harm performance.

Comment: @pKs , I did that by onclick='overlay()' . my css actually have  visibility: hidden; . I'll update my question's css for you to see

Comment: @Rain I used to put all those 3 height becuase I've already tried to put one but nothing's happen

Comment: That doesn't mean you will use duplicate  styles. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the HTML to this

```
<div id='overlay' class='hideOverlay'>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Now on clicking simply change the class.
Change your js to this

```
function overlay(e) 
{
    $('#overlay').attr('class', 'showOverlay');
}
```

Check the following style

```
.showOverlay
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: fixed;        
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.hideOverlay
{
    display:none;
}
```

Background-color is given just to check the div's visibility. Change it as per your choice.
It is nice to have some `opacity` for overlays to have a better look and feel effect.

Comment: Are you sure you need the background image. Also there is duplicate height and width in your class declaration.

Comment: which of those width and height declaration you think is right?

Comment: Simply use height:100% and width:100%.

Comment: look here so I can show you what is the result of your ans... http://i46.tinypic.com/30cshdx.png

Comment: Do you have overlay div inside any other div??? If yes, just put it directly inside body. So that it will have the entire screen as 100%.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14935/discussion-between-ivory-santos-and-rain)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: please look at my updated question, I already did that but it doesn't work

Comment: why you added this: height: auto !important; width: auto !important; width and height you already setted before.

Comment: I put 3 types of width and/or height declaration because I can't find the right one to put to make my background a 100% . Yes, the path is right

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: please look at my updated question, I already did that but it doesn't work